# How to incoporate jQuery UI into ASP.NET MVC 5 project that is on an offline system?

Tags: javascript, mvc, html, jquery, visual-studio

I am having some issues trying to incorporate jQuery UI into my project. I cannot use Nuget or anything else that goes to the internet, so I have downloaded the development package from the jQuery UI website, and have been trying to include the files from the download into the MVC 5 project in visual studio 2015 as follows.

1.) Created an MVC5 application in Visual Studio 2015.

2.) Built a full download on the jQuery UI website (http://jqueryui.com/download/) on a different computer with online access.

3.) Unzipped the downloaded folder and in the same location as the sample provided html (index.html) that is within this folder, I created my own html page to use some widgets to practice.

4.) Back in the offline computer, in the Content folder in the VS 2015 project, I created a folder called "css" and moved all the files from the download related to styling (i.e. the "images" folder) and all the files with css extension (including self-created ones) to here.

5.) In the Scripts folder of the VS2015 project, I created a folder called "jqueryui" and to here I moved the js files from the download, as well as the js file I created for my sample widget page.

6.) Still within the Scripts folder of the VS2015 project, I moved in the "jquery.js" file that was in the "external" folder in the unzipped download folder.

7.) Moved my sample html code into a new view cshtml I created in VS2015 called "Jqueryui.cshtml".

8.) In this view, I modified my style and script links as follows to update the paths:

In the html  tag:

```
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/mycustom.css">
```

Within the html  tag:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqueryui/mycustom.js"></script>
```

9.) Added code in the appropriate controller to access this view.

10.) Run the project and try to access the page in IE8, I get an error as follows in the debugger:

"Object doesn't support this property or method" 
On the following line of code (this is first of several lines of code that show this error):

( "#tabsuseradmin" ).tabs();

and then past the breakpoint, I get the page back with no styling or jQuery UI widgets whatsoever. The result is similar in the latest Firefox I downloaded from cnet.com today.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in getting jQuery UI running in a VS2015 MVC 5 project that is not connected to the internet. I believe I have covered all my steps in my attempt, and I am stuck on what to do now. The sample I created on my computer that is online works fine 
(I know it's irreleavant that it is online in the context of the sample page I created, but this makes me believe I am messing up the path information when I moved the files to the different directory structure of the VS 2015 project (step 8)).

What is the best way to include Jquery UI in an offline VS2015 project?

Thank you.

Comment: Please delete this question and re-ask it on Stack Overflow.  Code troubleshooting is off-topic here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I saw a question with 5 upvotes that is of a similar flavor as this. It is more of a setup question than a troubleshoot question. Therefore I do not think it is out of scope of this website. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224141/in-asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-add-initializer-javascript-to-a-control?rq=1

Comment: You'll get a better answer faster on Stack Overflow.  It's up to you.  You can wait out the close and delete cycle here, or you can ask it where it belongs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I asked there too, I don't see the need to delete here. More eyes the better.

Comment: We don't allow cross-posting here, sorry.  Stack Overflow has plenty of eyes on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good to know!

Comment: Um, the delete link works just as well here as it does on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why don't you just host the nuget packages locally? Download all of the necessary nuget packages on a machine with internet access, then copy them over to the offline computer, add the local folder to the nuget config in Visual Studio, and then add the packages as you normally would.

Comment: @EricKing Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into that and see if I can download the packages straight from the browser (the online access computer is restricted access).

Comment: @RobertHarvey The questions are no-longer similar.

Comment: @EricKing thanks for the tip, I was able to use a combination of online and offline steps to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download the nuget package file and install the package as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally

Then, to setup the jQuery UI properly in Visual Studio 2015, I followed this article:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/a-jquery-ui-based-date-picker-for-asp.net-mvc-5.html

Hope this helps someone else and thanks to @EricKing for the tip.